# How to change records on BigQuery from different rows to one row?

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

I have done inserting values into BigQuery from JSON file but my JSON file have multiple objects.

Eg:

```
{"A":{"queryID": "newId", "newCol": "newCol"}}
{"B":{"date":"2013-05-31 20:56:41", "device":"pc"}}
{"C":{"keyword": ["new", "ict"]}}
```

The results on BigQuery is one row per object, with empty rows for other objects. How do I do to make it all in one row with different columns?

```
def loadTable(http, service):
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/bigquery/v2/projects/" + projectId + "/jobs"

newresource = ('--xxx\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\n' + '\n' +
        '{\n' +
        '   "configuration": {\n' +
        '     "load": {\n' +
        '     "sourceFormat": "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON",\n' +
        '     "autodetect": "' + "True" + '",\n' +
        '      "destinationTable": {\n' +
        '        "projectId": "' + projectId + '",\n' +
        '        "datasetId": "' + datasetId + '",\n' +
        '        "tableId": "' + tableId + '"\n' +
        '      }\n' +
        '    }\n' +
        '  }\n' +
        '}\n' +
        '--xxx\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\n' +
        '\n')

f = open('samplejson.json', 'r')
newresource += f.read().replace('\n', '\r\n')

newresource += ('--xxx--\n')
print newresource

headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/related; boundary=xxx'}
resp, content = http.request(url, method="POST", body=newresource, headers=headers)

if not resp.status == 200:
    print resp
    print content
else:
    jsonResponse = json.loads(content)
    jobReference = jsonResponse['jobReference']['jobId']

while True:
    jobCollection = service.jobs()
    getJob = jobCollection.get(projectId=projectId, jobId=jobReference).execute()
    currentStatus = getJob['status']['state']

if 'DONE' == currentStatus:
    print "Done Loading!"
    return

else:
    print 'Waiting to load...'
    print 'Current status: ' + currentStatus
    print time.ctime()
    time.sleep(10)


def main(argv):
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("samplecredentials.json")
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery']
credentials = credentials.create_scoped(scope)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build('bigquery','v2', http=http)

loadTable(http, service)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend doing that final "assembling" into one row using below type of query (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
    ARRAY_AGG(A IGNORE NULLS) AS A,
    ARRAY_AGG(B IGNORE NULLS) AS B,
    ARRAY_AGG(C IGNORE NULLS) AS C
FROM `yourtable`
```

If you would have some extra field that would indicate which rows to combine/group together into one - for example some id - the query can look as below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  id,
  ARRAY_AGG(A IGNORE NULLS) AS A,
  ARRAY_AGG(B IGNORE NULLS) AS B,
  ARRAY_AGG(C IGNORE NULLS) AS C
FROM `yourtable`   
GROUP BY id
```